# CSS line break issue in Arabic translation

Tags: html, css, arabic

I am translating a page in arabic. I have a line (english equivalent) like this.

```
             here listed are member team your to assigned training the All
```

Whenever the line length increases, the line is wrapped and the line now looks like this.

```
                             here listed are member team your to assigned
                                                         training the All
```

which is of course not favorable. What I want is as following

```
                             member team your to assigned training the All
                                                           here listed are
```

Is there any CSS property to do so! If any of you has encountered such problem please enlighten me in the right direction.

**Edits**

The HTML

```
<p>here listed are member team your to assigned training the All</p>
```

The CSS

```
p {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Please show an actual example with relevant HTML, CSS, and real content, to reproduce the issue. I find it difficult to see why lines should be rendered bottom to top, no matter what the (horizontal) writing direction is, unless you have some special settings that ask for it (which would be abnormal for Arabic).

Answer (score 1):

You can add the

```
direction='rtl'
```

property to almost any HTML element to achieve this.

For Arabic webpages, you may find the HTML dir property on the body element useful too:

```
<body dir='rtl'>
    ...
</body>
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction

and for body dir='rtl': find the dir property on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes

Comment: Why do you think this has anything to do with the question?

Comment: The "undesirable" behaviour shown by the OP would be the result of right-aligning the text, but without setting it to display right-to-left. Having said that, it's quite strange that the "desired" output has only 3 words on the first line - I would assume it was intended for the top line to be full-length, and the line below it to be short. OP has not answered in the last hour though.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and this doesn't appear to resolve it. Will try to report back if I find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add `direction: rtl;` to the element's style, or prefix the text w/ the Right-to-Left encoding: "`&#8235;`".
You'll also want to add `text-align: right;` to properly right align.

HTML:

```
<p>&#8235;here listed are member team your to assigned training the All</p>
```

CSS:

```
p {
   // direction: rtl; Use this if you're not encoding the text
   text-align: right;
}
```

Gotcha:

If you applied this to a non RTL language, you'll see the behavior that you mentioned, this is because the English characters do not have the special encoding to denote that it is a RTL character.
If you enter in Arabic characters, it will wrap the words in the correct way.